# Какой предлог лучше выбрать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как лучше написать: "Читать Википедию на экране смартфона" или "Читать Википедию с экрана смартфона"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта встречаются, например:

(1) Как быстрее и удобнее читать **с экрана** компьютера. (2) Читать книги **на экране** с диагональю 3.5 дюйма не очень удобно.

Возможно, **читают на экране** конкретный текст, а **читать с экрана/на экране** ― здесь речь идет о способе  восприятия информации.

Поэтому лучше выбрать вариант: Читать Википедию  (любой текст) на экране смартфона.